# Calculate rolling total for calculated measure in powerBi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have calculated measures for total Hrs and quantity with that I calculated (Hrs/Qty), and now I need to calculate running total of that.
Expected result: 6.18,7.52 and so on. But it's giving incorrect result. What's is the correct Dax formula? Can we calculate rolling total for calculated measure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Power BI has a **Quick Measure** *Running Total* that is provided for exactly this purpose. And of course, you can also use *Measures* as *Base Value* for the calculation.

[image]

Comment: I have tried all possible ways still giving me wrong answer. That's why asking any experts help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this measures to achieve your goal:

```
% Of HR = SUMX(YourTable,DIVIDE([HR],[Qty]))

Rolling Total = CALCULATE(
                    [% Of HR],
                    FILTER(
                        ALL(YourTable[Week End Date]),
                        YourTable[Week End Date] <= MAX(YourTable[Week End Date])
                    )
                )
```

If we test our measure on a visual:

[image: GTST]